# Groupby using Django ORM

Tags: python, django

I have a table `Snapshot` where customer id is present scheme id is `present.Each` customer can multiple entries for same the scheme id.I want to form one query where I have to GroupBy the data for a customer based on scheme id.

As I am new to Django and python ,I have no idea on how to achieve this.

Any suggestions on how to fetch the data grouped on scheme id ?

Comment: Please, post your `models.py` to show the structure of tables involved in this issue and the code you are trying to use in order to achieve what you would like to do.

Comment: @raratiru Thank you, I got how to achieve it. I was writing the  wrong query in Django Orm.